# Camel validation error message

Tags: validation, exception, apache-camel

I have the following route in Camel

```
<route>
    <from uri="target/in"/>
    <doTry> 
        <to uri="validator:schema.xsd"/>
        <to uri="file:target/messages/validation/valid?fileName=a.xml"/>
        <doCatch> 
            <exception>org.apache.camel.ValidationException</exception>             
            <to uri="file:target/messages/validation/invalid?fileName=a.xml"/>
       </doCatch>
    </doTry> 
</route>
```

I want to get the error message when the XML file does not pass the validation like in this post

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/XML-Validation-getting-to-the-error-messages-using-Camel-td4768229.html

But how do I do that in Spring DSL?

Answer (score 2):

Like Claus states in your referenced thread:

> Exception cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, 
>   Exception.class);

So, this route should save your exception:

```
<route>
    <from uri="target/in"/>
    <doTry> 
        <to uri="validator:schema.xsd"/>
        <to uri="file:target/messages/validation/valid?fileName=a.xml"/>
        <doCatch> 
            <exception>org.apache.camel.ValidationException</exception>     
            <transform>
               <simple>${property.CamelExceptionCaught}</simple>
            </transform 
            <to uri="file:target/messages/validation/invalid?fileName=a.xml"/>
       </doCatch>
    </doTry> 
</route>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. It sends a message back, however it's not the message I was expecting. I'm getting

<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>Cannot store file: target\messages\validation\invalid\a.xml</faultstring>

Is there a problem with placing the XML file in another folder after the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the exception information in a file as in your sample code, you need to convert it to String.  Otherwise, you would get another exception about file cannot be stored because Camel cannot convert the schema validation exception to java.io.inputStream.

```
<route>
    <from uri="target/in"/>
    <doTry> 
        <to uri="validator:schema.xsd"/>
        <to uri="file:target/messages/validation/valid?fileName=a.xml"/>
        <doCatch> 
            <exception>org.apache.camel.ValidationException</exception>     
            <transform>
               <simple>${property.CamelExceptionCaught}</simple>
            </transform>
            <transform>
               <simple>${bodyAs(String)}</simple>
            </transform>
            <to uri="file:target/messages/validation/invalid?fileName=a.xml"/>
       </doCatch>
    </doTry> 
</route>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could send the exception in one file and the bad xml in another one.

```
<route>
    <from uri="target/in"/>
    <doTry> 
        <to uri="validator:schema.xsd"/>
        <to uri="file:target/messages/validation/valid?fileName=a.xml"/>
        <doCatch> 
            <exception>org.apache.camel.ValidationException</exception>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelOverruleFileName">
                <simple>${file:onlyname.noext}.${date:now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmssSSS}.xml</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="file:target/messages/validation/invalid/"/>
            <setBody>
                <simple>Got "${exception.message}" with this stack\n${exception.stacktrace}\n${body}</simple>
            </setBody>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelOverruleFileName">
                <simple>${file:onlyname.noext}.${date:now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmssSSS}.xml.error</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="file:target/messages/validation/invalid/"/>
        </doCatch>
    </doTry> 
</route>
```